# Is ML.NET compatible with TF2 saved_model format?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

It is mentioned on the official website that it is compatible, but when I try to load the model, I get errors. I did everything according to what is mentioned on the site. In addition, the input and output names of the model are also changed by ML.NET. The **serving_default** suffix is ​​added to the input, the **bias/Read/ReadVariableOp** suffix is ​​added to the output.
Is ML.NET compatible with TF2 saved_model format?